# rails group_by_day_of_week and sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, group-by

I have 2 models, Member and Slot 
and there is middle table between them named MemberSlot for has_many through relationship.

Now user comes and register in a slot.
Slot has field name slot_date.

For metrics on index page I have to show that how many times each member registered for slot in terms of day of week using date field slot_date.

Like

```
User    Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Saturday Sunday Total
---------------------------------------------------------------
Faisal  0      1        1         3        0       1       6
User2   1      0        0         0        1       2       4
User3   0      0        0         0        0       0       0
```

and than allow user to sort this table like monday or Total.

I tried to do it something like

```
Slot.joins(member_slots: [:member]).group("members.id").group_by_day_of_week(:slot_date).count
```

Issue with this is that I am not even able sort this by specific day and not possible by total and than have to fetch member in loop to show
So it not workable.

someone can suggest a proper way to handle this.

Waiting for your response.

Comment: Do you have jQuery installed? If so, you can use the jQuery plugin: https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: @hashrocket I have jquery installed but there is pagination with backend.
so front end thing 'll not work